# Some PHP functions do not properly work on mapped network drive

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-permissions, network-drive

I mounted network drive (running Windows Server 2008) on Ubuntu by adding command

```
//10.10.101.54/docflow /opt/lampp/htdocs/mount cifs user=administrator,password=wbaZaja43ik,rwx,user,auto,file_mode=6777,dir_mode=6777,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

in `/etc/fstab` but have troubles using PHP functions `is_file()` or `is_dir()` on files and directories on that mapped drive. These functions both return FALSE when called on existing files or directories - correct paths checked by `file_exists()` function which works correctly. PHP is running under 'administrator' user and have all privileges needed for manipulation.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from digitalaudiorock at gmail dot com's [comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php#98338) in the php manual:

> Just a note for anyone who encounters is_dir() returning false on CIFS
>   mount points or directories within those mount points on 2.6.31 and
>   newer kernels: Apparently in new kernels they've started using the
>   CIFS serverino option by default.  With Windows shares this causes
>   huge inode numbers and which apparently can cause is_dir() to return
>   false.  Adding the noserverino option to the CIFS mount will prevent
>   this.  This may only occur on 32 systems but I don't have a 64 bit
>   install to test against.

Comment: Mark, can't thank you enough!
Works like a charm now.
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! We hit this issue when running `composer install` on CentOS using PHP/Laravel/Composer (the error was "Composer could not find a composer.json file in ..."). The `noserverino` option did the trick.